# Where can I view Mono implementations of Math.* or Substring and the like

Tags: mono, open-source

Question says it all. I tried browsing through the latest [tag](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/tags/moon/1.9.1/mono/) but could not find the implementations for said functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Math.cs](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/corlib/System/Math.cs?view=markup) and [String.cs](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/corlib/System/String.cs?view=markup).  I agree it's a bit tricky, though Moon is definitely the wrong place.